# Why compute method is throwing error only in tree view?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-15

I'm using compute method to add records to the one2many field and it's working fine in form view but not in tree view. Can anyone help?

```
@api.depends("odoo_product_id")
def _compute_offers(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.odoo_product_id:
            offers = self.env['demo.offers'].search
                ([('product_id','=',rec.odoo_product_id.id)])
            for offer in offers:
                rec.shop_offer_ids = rec.shop_offer_ids + offer
```

It's throwing Compute method failed to assign Error in tree view only

Comment: Please add the error log to your question.

Comment: Also maybe not your error, but interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096793/odoo-13-how-to-solve-cachemiss-exception/61097419#61097419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compute method will fail to assign the field value for records where the `odoo_product_id` field is not set.

To fix that error use else to provide a default value for `shop_offer_ids` field.

***Example:***

```py
@api.depends("odoo_product_id")
def _compute_offers(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.odoo_product_id:
            offers = self.env['demo.offers'].search
                ([('product_id','=',rec.odoo_product_id.id)])
            rec.shop_offer_ids = offers.ids
        else:
            rec.shop_offer_ids = []
```

You can find an example in [website_event_questions](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fa58938b3e2477f0db22cc31d4f5e6b5024f478b/addons/website_event_questions/models/event_event.py#L43-L44) module